# Rails no longer works after Mac OSX El Capitan upgrade - `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've just started with Ruby/Rails and was going through a sample app. All was working fine until I upgraded OSX to El Capitan and then it no longer worked.

I uninstalled ruby, homebrew, rbenv, rails, etc... and re-installed fresh.

```
    rails new testapp
    ...
    ...
    create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
    create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
    create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
    run  bundle install
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:319:in `bundle_command'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:335:in `run_bundle'
    from (eval):1:in `run_bundle'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas? Thx.

Comment: Did you install bundler?

Comment: `gem install bundler`

Comment: Yup. If I make a new app (which produces the above error, but does make a folder structure), and bundle install, that works. However if I update the Gemfile to use the mysql2 gem, bundle install, and then rail s, get errors again. /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.1/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require': ....

  Reason: image not found - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.1/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle